# How to load a file into Elm REPL?

Tags: elm

For example:  in this repo, https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/ , how do I load one of the Elm files into elm repl, so I can evaluate functions, look at type signatures, etc ?

In Haskell I would use :l

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately the examples on the GitHub link don't expose anything, so you cannot import from them as-is. Since you have access to source code you can of course modify the sources to support this, so read on :)

In general, it is done in repl by using command `import`

> import SomeModule exposing (fun1, fun2)

`SomeModule` is the name of the module where to import, and `fun1` and `fun2` are functions to import. For importing all functions, use `(..)`

When the repl is started in the same folder as the modules, the import works. Maybe there's some option for repl to set the sources directory, but I could not find it.

But for something to be imported from a module, it needs to export it in the source file, like this for example

> module SomeModule exposing (fun1, fun2)

Answer (score 1):

This would be better placed as a comment on kaskelotti's good answer above, but in order to have the module in a different folder from where you start the repl, you can update the `elm.json` file associated with your project, adding "YOUR_DESIRED_DIRECTORY" to the "source-directories" array.

Also note that the filename needs to match the module name in the export and import statements:

so that

```
module SomeModule exposing (fun1, fun2)
```

would require a file named SomeModule.elm (at least in my experience)